# How to connect SpringBoot JMX beans with Jolokia?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx, jolokia

I'm using @EnableMBeanExport in a SpringBoot application to make my beans with @ManagedResource be available to the JMX server.  This works fine in simple local processes with VisualVM.

I'm now trying to add Jolokia into the mix, so I can reference those beans remotely with a REST service instead of setting up a remote RMI connection, which is annoying.

The Jolokia doc page at https://jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html says to use the following:

```
MBeanServer jolokiaServer = JolokiaMBeanServerUtil.getJolokiaMBeanServer();
```

However, there doesn't appear to be a "JolokiaMBeanServerUtil" class in Jolokia.

**Update**:

Ok, I found the artifact with the class, but the solution doesn't appear to be as simple as just declaring a bean with this value.  When I attempt to call a jmx method with a jolokia url, I get an exception like the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid object name. Key properties cannot be empty
    at org.jolokia.request.JmxRequestFactory.createGetRequest(JmxRequestFactory.java:99)
    at org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleGetRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:79)
    at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet$4.handleRequest(AgentServlet.java:470)
```

Comment: It's located under import org.jolokia.support.jmx.JolokiaMBeanServerUtil;

Comment: What artifact is that in?  It's not jolokia-core or jolokia-jmx.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It is in the jolokia-jmx artifact. I would think the docs would make this clear.